# React Native failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have been following this link to get started with react native 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

When i try to run this command `react-native run-android` in my project folder I get the following error

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: /home/knolly/Android/Sdk/platforms
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

  BUILD FAILED
  Total time: 16.225 secs
  Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
  Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have`

ANDROID_HOME is set in `~/.bashrc` and platforms folder contain android-23.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that you don't have installed the correct SDK required by RN.

If you open the file `android/app/build.gradle` you'll find the following line:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

Make sure that, on Android Studio, you have the correct SDK version installed:

[image: Installed SDK]

And the correct SDK tools:

[image: Installed SDK Tools]

Answer (score -1):

please try to open your "android" folder under react native project with "Android Studio".

It'll help you install all of missing build tool.